# File load issue from url

Tags: android

i am using Netroid﹕ [https://github.com/vince-styling/Netroid/issues libray for download images but getting me error 
[15806] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 206 for https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtp1/v/t1.0-9/12227065_1629121354019816_851133032645357923_n.jpg?oh=affbeb74597bb38b9a50eaa43687ba38&oe=57AFEC64
System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
04-29 20:34:49.273  20447-20464/com.photospring.frametoserver I/System.out﹕ KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false